# Xamarin Creating Navigation Page From Within TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

was following the provided example (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage) but no navigation page was ever populated from within my navigation page.

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <views:Page1 Title="1" />
    <NavigationPage Title="2">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:Page2 />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <views:Page2 Title="2b"/>
    <views:Page3 Title="3"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Tab 2b is loading correctly but i obviously cant produce a navigation page from this tab. Where tab 2 is not populating at all.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Tab 2b is loading correctly but i obviously cant produce a navigation page from this tab. Where tab 2 is not populating at all.

From this doc [Navigate within a tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#navigate-within-a-tab), **Navigation can be performed within a tab**, provided that the ContentPage object is wrapped in a NavigationPage object. This is accomplished by invoking the PushAsync method on the Navigation property of the ContentPage object.

For example, you add one ContentPage  `page2` in NavigationPage, you can use

`await Navigation.PushAsync (new UpcomingAppointmentsPage ());`

to navigate to `UpcomingAppointmentsPage` in page2 code behind.